# What is wrong in this array list

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

When i try to execute this program i amk getting error message Exception in thread. What iam doing wrong here, please let me know what is wrong

```
public class WhileExample1 {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //int number[] = {};
    int num[4] = {10, 20, 30, 40};
    int i=0;
    while (i<4) {
        System.out.println(num[4]);
        i++;
    }


}
```

}

When i execute this program i am getting this error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
Syntax error on token "4", delete this token

at loop_demo.WhileExample1.main(WhileExample1.java:6)
```

Comment: `int num[] = {10, 20, 30, 40};`

Comment: And that's an array, not an "array list".

Comment: *["amk"](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=amk)* - now that's a funny typo.

Comment: Hint: learn java syntax. It isn't that hard ;-)

Comment: And you dont **execute** the program. You try to compile it. Compiler error messages are not **runtime execution** problems.

Answer (score 3):

Don't use :

```
int num[4] = {10, 20, 30, 40};
//      ^--------------------------no need to set the size here
```

Instead :

```
int num[] = {10, 20, 30, 40};
```

and to print values of your array you have to use `num[i]`:

```
while (i < num.length) {
//            ^^-------------------to avoid any problem of size use array.lenght instead
    System.out.println(num[i]);
    //                     ^-----------------print num[i] not num[4]
    i++;
}
```

---

**Note** there are no element `num[4]`, because the index start from `0` not `1`, so `int num[4] = {10, 20, 30, 40};` mean :

```
num[0] = 10
num[1] = 20
num[2] = 30
num[3] = 40
```

---

I suggest to read this documentation [Arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/java/99/arrays#t=201705151251134273336)

Comment: Bad question, good answer. But that wont prevent me from hitting the "delete" link on the question as soon as that thing goes closed.

Comment: mmm, you put me in baffling @GhostCat delete my answer or not!

Comment: I am not deleting the ANSWER. But the QUESTION. And I dont DELETE, I put in a DELETE VOTE. Those are two different things ;-)

Comment: no i don't mean you delete my answer, i meant that i should delete my answer or let it :-)

Comment: hahah, you are really kind @GhostCat no i will not thank you for the advice <3

Comment: ;-) ... and nice to see that the question and your two upvotes are still here ;-) x2

Answer (score -1):

i don't see any arrayList here , if do you want to implement an arrayList 
do something like this

```
ArrayList <Integer>list=new ArrayList();
 list.add(1); list.add(2);list.add(3);
```

however you are using normal array;

and the wrong is you are trying to access the index number 4 which is array doesn't have it, why?
becuase the array index starts from 0 so in your case

10 has the index [0] , 20 has the index[1], 30 has the index[2], 40 has the index [3] there is no index[4] here